# Trim space inside the anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is here.....

```
 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.home.test.com/test/redirector.jspx?        action=ref&cname=test_EDITORIAL&ckey=2448719&cc=US&lc=eng&mcr=true&cmpid=MA43304BL" style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:
            #0085d5" >download the brochure</a><br><br>
```

I want in this way

```
 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.home.test.com/test/redirector.jspx?action=ref&cname=test_EDITORIAL&ckey=2448719&cc=US&lc=eng&mcr=true&cmpid=MA43304BL"style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:#0085d5" >download the brochure</a><br><br>
```

i want to remove the space between the anchor tag. As it is generated dynamically in `html`, I have to pick the whole `html` and modify it.You can't rely on `parent` or `child` elements because it can be with or without anything.I also dont want to use the `/n`. Is there any way to pick all anchor tags and `trim` the space between it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** callback and remove all the spaces using `.replace` with proper regex:

```
$('a').attr('href', function (_, val) {
    return val.replace(/\s/g, '');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ26S/)**

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is to fix in your **server side** to let the output be right, but not using javascript to fix such issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use some selector for targeting this anchor tag. you can use:

```
$('a').attr('href',$('a').attr('href').replace(/ /g,''))
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v984m/)**